# setar valor pela função success ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Na função success não estou conseguindo setar um valor de uma div com o conteúdo da variável data

```
$(document).on("click", ".js-busca-previsao-chegada", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var familia = $(this).attr("js-familia");
    var esferico = $(this).attr("js-esferico");
    var cilindrico = $(this).attr("js-cilindrico");
    $
        .ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/buscaprevisaochegada",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "familia": familia,
                "esferico": esferico,
                "cilindrico": cilindrico

            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#js-tooltip-previsao").text(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Você verificou o que esta chegando na variável data?

Comment: quando coloco console data não aparece nada meu problema está justamente  success: function(data)

Comment: O problema pode esta na sua url "buscaprevisaochegada"

Comment: antes ela retornava uma string e não um json efetuei a troca aqui e agora o valor passa no console. Obrigada @WictorChaves